# Does the Hot Tub in the Castle allow me to improve relationships?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

Does the Hot Tub in the Castle allow me to improve relationships?

Or is it more of just a fanservice thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "fanservice"?

Comment: @ardaozkal Reading up a little bit about the game would benefit you greatly here.

Comment: If it does improve relationships, it's probably going to be a very minor thing; most of your relationship improvements are going to be spending time beside them in battle.

Comment: It's related to content that was censored from the western release of the game.

Comment: @Avery - Fanservice is normally a scene in games and media that are slightly racey: very suggestive outfits, wardrobe malfunctions, pervy camera angles, etc. It's a common term in the realms of content from japan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real use for the Hot Spring is upgrading it to max to get an extra character - an Onmyoji called Izana on Birthright and Conquest, or a Master of Arms called Fuga in Revelation. They join at different points in each route.

Other than that it has no use other than as a "special interactions" space, most notably if the Player Avatar has a spouse and/or children. Interactions there have no effect on relationships.

Comment: Does it improve relationships though? You didn't really say whether it did or not.

Comment: The fact that i did not mention that, along with the phrasing of the last paragraph should be your answer. But i will rephrase a few bits to clarify

Comment: @Vemonus - is that better now?